# Delete all data from an attribute in CoreData

Tags: ios, swift, core-data

How to delete all data for example from an **attribute** `<name>`, **not Entity**, from attribute. I have an entity name - Users, attribute - name and I don't know how to delete all data from an attribute.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

for delete the all data you can use this function

```
func deleteAllData(entity: String) {

    let appDelegate = UIApplication.sharedApplication().delegate as! AppDelegate
    let managedContext = appDelegate.managedObjectContext
    let fetchRequest = NSFetchRequest(entityName: entity)
    fetchRequest.returnsObjectsAsFaults = false

    do
    {
        let results = try managedContext.executeFetchRequest(fetchRequest)
        for managedObject in results
        {
            let managedObjectData:NSManagedObject = managedObject as! NSManagedObject
            managedContext.deleteObject(managedObjectData)
            print("Deleted")
        }

    } catch let error as NSError {
        print(error)
    }
}
```

and after that call the function like this

```
deleteAllData(entity: "your Entity name")
```

Answer (score 0):

You have to set that `attibute` to **nil** and save the `context`. This is how you have to remove the attribute from entity. You can't delete it like how an entity is deleted from coreData.

Answer (score 0):

I just renewed Rahuld and Piet.t code for Swift and it works.

```
func deleteAllData(entity: String) {
    
    let appDelegate = UIApplication.shared.delegate as! AppDelegate
    let managedObjectContext = appDelegate.persistentContainer.viewContext
    let fetchRequest = NSFetchRequest<NSManagedObject>(entityName: entity)
    fetchRequest.returnsObjectsAsFaults = false
    
    do
    {
        let results = try managedObjectContext.fetch(fetchRequest)
        for managedObject in results
        {
            let managedObjectData:NSManagedObject = managedObject
            managedObjectContext.delete(managedObjectData)
            print("Deleted")
        }
        
    } catch let error as NSError {
        print(error)
    }
    
    try? managedObjectContext.save()
    self.fetch(entity: "ListItem")
    
}
```

and after that call the function like this

```
deleteAllData(entity: "your Entity name")
```

in addition after you need to show the result so you will fetch your data again.
the below function can be used for it

```
func fetch(entity: String) {
  //Veritabanındaki  bilginin ekrana gelmesi için veriyi çekme işlemi
 let appDelegate = UIApplication.shared.delegate as? AppDelegate
    let managedObjectContext = appDelegate?.persistentContainer.viewContext
    let fetchRequest = NSFetchRequest<NSManagedObject>.init(entityName: entity)
    data =  try! managedObjectContext!.fetch(fetchRequest)
    tableView.reloadData()
}
```

use it like:

```
self.fetch(entity: "your entity name")
```

or like this:

```
fetch(entity: "your entity name")
```